# Run java application with OpenJDK

Tags: java, jre, openjdk

I am trying to run [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdfbookmarks/) application on my machine (Windows 11). I installed the latest version of OpenJDK from [here](https://adoptium.net/download). In my command line I can write

```
> java -version
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I try to run the application I get an error that it requires java runtime version 1.6. Is the JRE not backwards compatible? How can I make this work without allowing [Oracle](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2494794/oracle-will-continue-to-bundle--crapware--with-java.html) to install anything to my machine?

Comment: java versions become less and less backward compatible the further they are away from the version the application was built on. java deprecates components of the runtime with each release. you might try it with 1.8 or 1.11 instead of 1.17.

Answer (score 0):

I can get it to work by navigating to the folder in a powershell and typing

```
java -jar jpdfbookmarks.jar
```

However, I will accept as the *correct* answer how to make this work the expected way by just opening the application (or explaining why that's impossible)

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Java installed? What is the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set to?